# How to use rails3 with RedCloth. require 'RedCloth' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textile, redcloth

I have installed RedCloth, by using the devkit. Using gem install RedCloth.

If I use plain irb, then require 'RedCloth' works fine.

But if I use rails console and do require 'RedCloth', it says it can't find file to load.

Please help.

Rails 3.0.0
RedCloth 4.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is RedClotch included in your Gemfile, and have you run `bundle install` since updating your Gemfile?

I don't believe Rails 3 will allow you to include gems that are not in the Gemfile. I'm not quite sure about the inner workings of bundler, but I believe the Rails app considers your Gemfile it's "only source" for loading gems.

Comment: what is a gem file? and where is it located?

Comment: In a default Rails 3 app, it'll be at the top level directory, and it'll be named Gemfile (no extension) -- you can open it with any text editor, and subsequently run `bundle install` to parse/process that Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to do the following on Windows XP and above!

1. Installed Ruby via [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
2. Downloaded DevKit from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
3. From the Ruby enhanced CMD prompt, "ruby dk.rb init", followed by "ruby dk.rb install"
4. Downloaded the SQLLite DLL files from here: [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_7_3.zip), copied them into the   C:\Windows directory
5. From the Ruby enhanced CMD prompt, "Gem install RedCloth"
6. Added "Gem RedCloth" to gemfile
7. "bundle install"

These steps worked for me! I don't understand why people have such a hard time with Ruby on Windows. That's all I develop on and it works fine.